# Can I access Facebook API's without an api_key?

Tags: facebook, api-key

Is it possible to access Facebook APIs for logging in a user, or to allow a user to become a fan of a fan page through a third party site, without actually creating an app on facebook?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you [create a fab page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php) directly for users to become fans for that page? And as far as i know, you can not access facebook API without API key.

Comment: I want to provide the ability to let a user become a fan without actually going to the FB site... and that too without having to use the fan box. Hence wanted to know abt accessing APIs without the key...

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the API without creating an application and getting an API key. There are a [small number of API queries that will work without the user having added an application](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/Category:Sessionless_API) or even interacted with it but they generally on retrieve very basic data.

There's certainly no programmable way of making a user a fan of a page without using a [fan box widget](http://www.facebook.com/facebook-widgets/) or having them do it directly through the site. This is because the post_form_id value which Facebook uses for these kinds of interactions is only present on pages served from facebook.com and is never accessible to the developer. To allow otherwise would open up the system to all kinds of exploitation.

I've no idea what problem you're trying to solve anyway. Creating an application API key is no hardship (and it doesn't have to be an active application for session-less queries - just create an app and grab the keys) and the fan box widget can be styled with CSS, as long as you follow the basic rules that Facebook has set out.

Comment: The problem i am trying to address is to allow a user to login to FB through a third party site, by calling some FB APIs, to which i'll pass the username, password submitted by the user. Now i dnt have an app on FB, so was looking for some way in which i can call the login api without the api_key (if at all its possible). 

Similar issue for becoming a fan without actually relying on FB or the api key of an app. 

In case i want to use an api_key, then is it possible to use the key of a dummy app i create which is not even submitted to FB?

Comment: Logging a user into FB through a third party site is against their terms of service. (And there isn't a login API.) I think you need to do some more reading on what the API is there for - your questions don't really make sense.
You don't need an API key for the fan widget - just the ID of the page. It's a simple iframe you can include anywhere and detects the user's login status automatically.